# Change the color of all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to change the 'accent' color of a website. Does anyone know an efficient way to change the background-color, color and border-color of all elements with the color 'magenta' for example? Is there a way to detect for the property magenta in the CSS file and replace it with another color? I am building an extension for a website (and would prefer not to append a massive CSS file with the color change) and cannot change the source code of the site.

If there is anything unclear please feel free to ask.

Comment: You can change using `css()` , eg : `$('.selector'),css('color','red');`

Comment: Find-replace in your stylesheet the desired color with the new one.

Comment: I do not have access to the source code of the website, I am building an extensions. And I am looking to replace **a lot** of properties here, it would be inefficient to use .css(). But thanks for the replies.

Comment: "it would be inefficient to use .css()" -- Never heard that before when talking about editing styles.

Comment: edit styles in browser, copy rules to stylesheet and import that

Comment: When talking about 50-100+ classes that requires a lot of manual work and appends unnecessary code to the site as well as slows down the performance of the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Loop through all of the elements, and if the computed color is magenta, set the new color on the element.

```js
const magenta = 'rgb(255, 0, 255)';
const green = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)';

const getValue = (elem, property) => 
    window.getComputedStyle(elem, null)
        .getPropertyValue(property);

const changeColors = () =>
    document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((elem) => {
        const backgroundColor = getValue(elem, 'background-color');
        const borderColor = getValue(elem, 'border-color');
        const color = getValue(elem, 'color');

        if (backgroundColor === magenta) {
            elem.style.backgroundColor = green;
        }

        if (borderColor === magenta) {
            elem.style.borderColor = green;
        }

        if (color === magenta) {
            elem.style.color = green;
        }    
    });
```

```css
.background {
    background-color: magenta;
}
.color {
    color: magenta;
}
.border {
    border: solid 2px magenta;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="background">Background</div>
    <div class="color">Text</div>
    <div class="border">Border</div>
    <button onclick="changeColors()">Change Colors</button>
</body>
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this if there is any other alternative.  Changing the CSS up front would be ideal, and not using JS at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazingly useful in Discord to change role colors locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can change multiple css properties using jQuery **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method:

```
$(".yourCssSelector").css({
    "background-color": "magenta",
    "color": "#00FF00",
    "border-color": "blue"
});
```

or using vanilla JS:

```
// choose an element using any of these:
var elem = document.getElementById('your-id');
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('your-class-name')[0];
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]; // indexes are for example

elem.style.borderColor = 'blue';
elem.style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
elem.style.color = '#00FF00';
```

Yes, it will require many CSS changes. You want to change the appearence of the whole web-site - of course, it will. I don't think that your web-site's designer has colored every element with `magenta` by inline styling - there are existent styles, choose selectors and classes wisely and you will easily do this.